# Deserialize object in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

Please help me to solve this issue. I am try to call `DeserializeObject` using `JsonConvert`, but it's returning an empty result to my view. My API response is fine and receives data, but I cannot deserialize it into a company model.

This is my code:

```
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<company>(apiResponse);
}
```

My company model is:

```
public class company
{
    public string bankAccount { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string bankName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string cif { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string creationDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string fiscalAttribute { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string id { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string locationAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string locationCounty { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string nrRegCom { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string passwordHash { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string privilegeKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string registrationState { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string storedHardwareID { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string subscriptionExpirationDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string subscriptionID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string actionConfirmationID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string updateDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The API call is returning a result in JSON format:

```
{
    "company": {
        "bankAccount": "777",
        "bankName": "777",
        "cif": "123",
        "creationDate": "2023-01-16T17:38:45.962Z",
        "email": "pankaj@gmail.com",
        "fiscalAttribute": "123",
        "id": "f0e3bfef5bcf40c987713153e55dceef",
        "locationAddress": "india",
        "locationCounty": "india",
        "name": "pankaj",
        "nrRegCom": "123",
        "passwordHash": "7c78eea7a591b0c8a4dad680372e35ca12e11cffdac5c69a39700c8014fbcc82",
        "phoneNumber": "88888858",
        "privilegeKey": "",
        "registrationState": 1,
        "storedHardwareID": "",
        "subscriptionExpirationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "subscriptionID": "",
        "actionConfirmationID": "",
        "updateDate": "2023-01-16T17:38:45.962Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a root object that contains a _company_. You need to deserialize such root not directly the company data. Or better change, if possible, the code that serialize that data

Comment: The JSON document is an object with a `company` property that contains the same fields as the `Company` type. It doesn't match `Company`. `"company"` is an attribute name, not a type

Comment: @Steve i am not able to understand it properly, pls suggest with a code change, thanks

Comment: To understand the problem create a class named RootObject. The only property for this class will be a _public Company company {get;set;}_ Now deserialize RootObject instead of Company. After deserialization the _company_ property will have your data. So, you understand why you should change how the serialization code works (or adapt)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not able to understand what you are trying to say.. can you pls explain with code change. Thanks

Comment: @Steve thanks for your help its working now with the code ` Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(apiResponse);` now how can i return data to my view

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your returned JSON is an object that has a key of "company" on the root level. Imagine the outer {} as an unnamed object which contains the property "Company", which is an object with its own properties.

Now you have 2 different options:

1:

Create a class that acts as a wrapper around the company to reflect the JSON structure on your .NET objects correctly, e.g.

```
public class CompanyWrapper
{
    public Company company { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your JSON result onto this wrapper, it should work now.
However this should be avoided in this case because the wrapper itself provides absolutely no other value to your use-case besides, well, acting as a wrapper.

2:

Another way would be to refactor your API call result, if you have access to the API to return the root {} object without the additional, useless "company"-key on the root level. If you don't have access and don't want to touch the JSON result otherwise, then use the wrapper approach.

Also keep in mind that the standard naming convention for classes and properties in C# is Pascal-Case, which means that the first letter of a given name should be uppercase.

Comment: Hi thanks for you help, i have all the data into CompanyWrapper, then how can i assign all to my company class then return it to view  ` Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(apiResponse);
                        company = .......................
                    }
  
                }
            }
            return View(company);`